# Filter rows with unique value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter lines that contain only one value (the others is Nan).

I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"text":["NLTK is a leading platform for building Python","Natural Language Processing with Python provides a practical introduction to programming for language processing","Written by the creators of NLTK","Learning-oriented lessons that introduce a particular gensim feature","These goal-oriented guides demonstrate how to solve","Blog posts, tutorial videos, hackathons","spaCy is designed to help you do real work","spaCy excels at large-scale information extraction tasks","spaCy is the best way to prepare text for deep learning"], 
                "col1":[np.nan,"NLTK",np.nan,np.nan,"spacy",np.nan,"gensim",np.nan,np.nan], 
                "col2":[np.nan,"gensim","NLTK",np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,"spacy",np.nan,"gensim"], 
                "col3":[np.nan,"spacy",np.nan,np.nan,np.nan,"gensim","NLTK",np.nan,np.nan]})

df_NLTK = df[df[["col1","col2","col3"]].apply(lambda x: x == "NLTK", axis = 1)]
```

**My output:**

```
    text    col1    col2    col3
    NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
    NaN     NLTK    NaN     NaN
    NaN     NaN     NLTK    NaN
    ...
```

**Good output:**

```
    text                                                 col1   col2    col3
    Written by the creators of NLTK                      NaN    NLTK    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df.loc[df[["col1", "col2", "col3"]].isna().sum(axis=1).eq(2)]
```

Outputs:

```py
                                                text  ...    col3
2                    Written by the creators of NLTK  ...     NaN
4  These goal-oriented guides demonstrate how to ...  ...     NaN
5            Blog posts, tutorial videos, hackathons  ...  gensim
8  spaCy is the best way to prepare text for deep...  ...     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
df[df[["col1","col2","col3"]].apply(lambda x: x.isna(), axis=0).sum(axis=1) == 2]
```

Output:

```
text    col1    col2    col3
2   Written by the creators of NLTK NaN NLTK    NaN
4   These goal-oriented guides demonstrate how to ...   spacy   NaN NaN
5   Blog posts, tutorial videos, hackathons NaN NaN gensim
8   spaCy is the best way to prepare text for deep...   NaN gensim  NaN
```